# stop default jsonification of response in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView  listEmployees(HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getList();
        return new ModelAndView("hello").addObject("employees", employees);
        }
```

Here is my relevant pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I see employees object automatically converted to json

Then i tried

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But still result is getting converted to json ?

Comment: Do you have your controller annotated as `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`? The first one defaults to a JSON response.

Comment: What do you have in your `hello` page?